# How to manage an external library instance in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

I'm trying to use [Quill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) in a react component. I'm creating the quill instance after the component mounts. Quill has a `getContents()` method that will return the contents in the editor which I would like to post to the server.

It doesn't appear that I can use the quill instance in any handlers that I define, which as the saveSummary below.

I would like to generally know how creating and using these instance methods should be handled with React

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { actions } from 'react-redux-form'
import Quill from 'quill'
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

@connect((store) => {
  return {
    ...store
  }
})
export default class QuillEditor extends React.Component{
  // Constructor to set element state

  componentDidMount() {

    var toolbarOptions = [
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
      ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

      [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],
      [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
      [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],
      [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],
      [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],

      [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
      [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

      [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
      [{ 'font': [] }],
      [{ 'align': [] }],

      ['clean']
    ];

    var quill = new Quill('#quill-area', {
      modules: { toolbar: toolbarOptions },
      theme: 'snow'
    });

  }

  componentWillMount() {

  }

  saveSummary = () => {
    console.log(this.refs.quillEditor.childNodes[0].innerHTML)
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <div className="profile-quill">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.saveSummary}>Save</button>
        <div ref="quillEditor" id="quill-area"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you try `react` supported libraries like https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill

Comment: I tried to use it, but react was throwing an error because they're creating another react instance inside of it or something. I would love to just use the component, but I couldn't figure out how to get it working.

Comment: Here we have the docs to start with https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill#quick-start

Comment: I have looked into this

I call `import ReactQuill from 'react'quill`

but then the console throws the error 

    `addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (detail).`

I was unable to find a solution

Comment: `import ReactQuill from 'react'quill` must be changed to `import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';`

Comment: sorry, that was a typo in the comment, and it is correct as you have presented it in my actual code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129894/discussion-between-digitaldisaster-and-jyothi-babu-araja).